# PowerShell ISE .jpg and .png summary size (Windows and its subdirectories)

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a solution to this problem: Find the summary size of .jpg and .bmp files in Windows and its subdirectories.
I use the following commands:

```
Get-ChildItem -Force -Depth 2 -Path C:\Windows\ | Where-Object -Property Extension -Match "\.(bmp|jpg)$" | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum | Select-Object -Property Sum
```

How do I count the actual summary size without getting an access error:
The output is:

```
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Force -Depth 2 -Path C:\Windows\ | Where-Object -Prope ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\CSC\v2.0.6:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
 

     Sum
     ---
35241685
```

Thank You.

Comment: Try to add `-Force` to `Get-ChildItem` arguments. Also make sure to set `$jpg_sum = 0`, otherwise you will add to value of previous script run.

Comment: Unfortunetely, didn't help.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the error message in text format.

Comment: Done.Tried another approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all *.bmp and *.jpg files and to sum their length you can do:

```
$measure = Get-ChildItem -path $env:SystemRoot* -Include @('*.bmp','*.jpg') -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property length -sum
```

But this is quite slow. By using the parameter "-Filter" this runs much much faster, but you have to do 2 calls as the parameter "-Filter" only accepts a string and not a array:

```
#Get files
$files = @(
    get-childitem -path $env:SystemRoot -Filter '*.jpg' -Recurse -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
    get-childitem -path $env:SystemRoot -Filter '*.bmp' -Recurse -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
)

#Get count and sum
$measure = $files | Measure-Object -Property length -sum
```

Finally to avoid the "path too long" issue:

```
#Get files
$files = @(
    get-childitem -pspath "\\?\C:\Windows" -Filter '*.jpg' -Recurse -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
    get-childitem -pspath "\\?\C:\Windows" -Filter '*.bmp' -Recurse -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
)

#Get count and sum
$measure = $files | Measure-Object -Property length -sum
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry

Comment: Sorry,still this with both approaches,even though the Sum property of $measure gets the needed size.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
At line:1 char:12
+ $measure = Get-ChildItem -path $env:SystemRoot* -Include @('*.bmp','* ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], PathTooLongException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.PathTooLongException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand`

Comment: hehe "path too long" ok... this should help you: ```get-childitem -pspath "\\?\C:\Windows" -Filter '*.jpg' -Recurse -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue``` - please let me know if it did the trick

Comment: `get-childitem : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-childitem -pspath "\\?\C:\Windows" -Filter '*.jpg' -Recurse -Erro ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand` ... unfortunately

Comment: which powershell version do you use?

Comment: Powershell ISE 5.1.22000.65, ran as admin.

Comment: only an ISE issue  - run the command native on PowerShell and you won't get the error message.... - tested from my side on PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.2.6

Comment: Thank You! I'll use the second one from your first answer.